# How to set `\autocite{}` of `biblatex` as `\tiny` using beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, fontsize, automation

I would like to produce `beamer` slides with `biblatex` and to set the font size of the citations with `\autocite{}` as `\tiny` while keeping the font size of the citations with `\textcite` default (`\normalsize`).

Currently, I use `\renewcommand*{\citesetup}{\tiny}` but this command sets the font size of all citations as `\tiny`.

Is there any way to modify the `beamer` or `biblatex` settings to achieve this?

[image]

Note but I do not want to get this effect by typing like `\tiny \autocite{...} \normalsize` by hand. I am seeking more systematic ways.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@Manual{R-rmarkdown,
  title = {rmarkdown: Dynamic Documents for R},
  author = {JJ Allaire and Yihui Xie and Jonathan McPherson and Javier Luraschi and Kevin Ushey and Aron Atkins and Hadley Wickham and Joe Cheng and Winston Chang and Richard Iannone},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 2.3},
  url = {https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown},
}

@Book{knitr2015,
  title = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year = {2015},
  edition = {2nd},
  note = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
  url = {https://yihui.org/knitr/},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[%
  style = apa6,
  sortcites = true, 
  sorting = nyt, 
  backend = biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\renewcommand*{\citesetup}{%
  \tiny
}

\title{Untitled}
\author{CLRR}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{R Markdown}

This is a markdown variant by \textcite{R-rmarkdown}.

This is knitr \autocite{knitr2015}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{}
  \bibliographytrue
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, when `\citesetup` is used we cannot yet access the delimiter context to branch on the exact citation command we are in. A straightforward, but slightly more tedious solution is to use the wrapper command of `\DeclareCiteCommand` to wrap `\parencite` (which is what `\autocite` becomes here) not only in parentheses, but in tiny parentheses.

The original definitions can be found in [`apa.cbx` (ll. 484-503 in v8.5)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/b0ffa503ae8019e0134172d29bb14be4a41d74d3/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/cbx/apa6.cbx#L484). We only define a new `\mkbibtinyparens` and use that instead of `\mkbibparens`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[%
  style = apa6,
  sortcites = true, 
  backend = biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand*{\mkbibtinyparens}[1]{{\tiny\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibtinyparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkbibtinyparens]{\parencite}
  {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibtinyparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{R Markdown}

This is a markdown variant by \textcite{sigfridsson}.

This is knitr \autocite{nussbaum}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tiny parencite, normal textcite.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this brilliant answer! I accepted and up-voted it!